# Rout Url 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: vue.js, iis, deployment, http-redirect

I have Error when Refresh page or write any extra word for URL like https://example.com/signin
the Error is 404 - File or directory not found, my project is dotnet core api and vuejs deployed on IIS, if I write URL like https://example.com it works well

I expect that the error is in the URL in files Vue.js
or in deploy vuejs in iis

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS is trying to serve an HTML page that doesn't exist.  Single Page Applications only have one page, so anything other than the root index needs to be redirected so that vue-router can handle it instead of IIS.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#Internet-Information-Services-IIS-

1. Install IIS UrlRewrite(opens new window)
2. Create a web.config file in the root directory of your site with the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you yoduh . I already created a web.config as you mentioned, and the problem was solved. Thank you again for the response